# Single select from template record oracle

Tags: oracle

Due to lack of terminology in my head, let's say I've got 1 record from users table with these attributes :

```
Name   | Surname | Height | Weight
Person   X         6,2      190
```

How do I find other users with same height and weight as a person x with single select?

**Update:**

I have this on me now :

```
Select *
from users
where height = (select height from users where name = 'x')
and weight = (select weight from user where name = 'x');
```

Can I somehow fire this inner query once, because I'm reusing the same db record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join the table on itself using a table alias;

This does the trick:

```
Select u1.*
from 
     users u1
     inner join users u2 on u1.weight = u2.weight and u1.height = u2.height
where u2.name = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select *
from your_table
where height = '6,2'
and weight = 190;
```

or

```
Select *
from your_table
where height = (select height from your_table where person = x)
and weight = (select weight from your table where person = x);
```

Comment: I have the case 2, I should have put that in my original question